# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Turtle'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just started using Python, and I really want to use Visual Studio Code as my IDE. I can print "Hello World" no problem. I'm trying to use the `import Turtle` and I'm getting an error. Does anyone know how to install it? I appreciate any help! Or guide on how to get started with Python!

CODE:

```py
import Turtle
msg = "Hello"
print(msg)
```

ERROR :

```
python /mnt/d/getting-started-python/vstoolbox/hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/getting-started-python/vstoolbox/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Turtle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Turtle'
```

Comment: When I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` in Python my very first suspicion is a misspelled module name. Python tracebacks are wonderfully descriptive but be patient learning how to read them!

Answer (score 0):

it should be just import turtle (lowercase "t") and you should be able to install it

Comment: I changed it to turtle, lower case "t" ! and it's saying i don't have a module name 'tkinter' but i never call it?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/getting-started-python/vstoolbox/hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 107, in <module>
    import tkinter as TK
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Ubuntu or Debian then you need to install `tkinter` explicitly (I think it's `python3-tkinter`).

Comment: Thank you, but why is this true, do you know? Isn't tkinter supposed to be part of Python's standard library?

Comment: It's due to Debian packaging policy. Anything they considered an application or something they already package outside of a project is to be made available separate. Same reason venv and pip are not installed automatically on any Debian-based system. They have been asked to change, but instead they plan to eventually have a `python3-full` in the next version of Debian for people to install (https://packages.debian.org/sid/python3-full).

Answer (score 0):

I can advise you to open your shell, then on the file tab, click open module :
try turtle and then tkinter. if it is opened,there is no problem and you can work on it.
If not just istall them using the pip from your cmd using the pip installer from [here](https://pypi.org/project/turtle/)
hope I helped you, any help just comment this.

Answer (score 0):

just type `sudo apt install python3-tk`
this should solve all the tkinter related problems and also the  import tkinter as Tk problem

Answer (score -2):

Just use pip to install turtle, there are loads of tutorials online on how to install libraries using pip. If you are on windows use pip install turtle or pip3 install turtle on Linux

Comment: For good python tutorials you can try using udemy I learnt python there